# Trying to use a if command to detect parts of a set command

Tags: batch-file

I use the set command and use the if command to detect what you typed to decide what to do next:

```
@ echo off
color 4A
echo Hello!
pause >nul
echo Who are you?
set /p name="name:"
echo Hello, %name%!
pause >nul
```

the problem:

```
set /p talk="talk here:>"
if %talk%="hello" echo Hello!
```

of course with

```
pause >nul
cls
```

at the end, that's not the problem.
when it says >, I type in hello but it doesn't work. It just closes the file. If I type something
else eg.

```
talk here:>Hello!
```

then it says

```
Hello! was not expected at the time
```

and closes. how do I get it to detect I said hello and respond with Hello! ?
please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `pause >NUL` seems to be doing something odd. Try this:

```
@echo off
echo Hello!
pause >nul
echo Who are you?
set /p name="name:"
echo Hello, %name%!
pause >nul
set /p talk="talk here:>"
if "%talk%"=="hello" echo Hello!
```